# How to force a website to display in desktop version

Tags: .net, maui

How to force a website to display in desktop version? I have a website, and I need to access from Android or iOS, but in desktop site not mobile site. Or if I can handle also in .net maui blazor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to achieve it:

page.xaml:

```xml
<WebView Source="..." WidthRequest="500" HeightRequest="700"/>
```

page.xaml.cs:

```cs
public MainPage()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  ModifyWebView();
}

void ModifyWebView()
{
  Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.WebViewHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping(
    "MyCustomization",
    (handler, view) =>
    {
#if ANDROID
      handler.PlatformView.Settings.UserAgentString =
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36";
#elif IOS
      handler.PlatformView.CustomUserAgent =
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36";
#endif
    });
}
```